# how to set angularjs single page application for social share

Tags: angularjs, html, facebook, express

I'm trying to set social sharing with SPA using Express.js and AngularJS.
Thing is, I want to share dynamic content, so I'm using [angular-facebook-factory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-facebook-factory) to get facebook buttons. Buttons work, params are set, just the image, title and description params that I pass never get to facebook share popup screen.

```
$scope.shareEvent = function (event) {
        console.log('verify values: ', event.image); // works fine!
        FacebookService.share({
            href: 'http://www.example.com/event/'+event_id+'/', // this value is passed
            title: event.title, // Not shown
            description: event.desc, // Not shown
            image: event.image // Not shown
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.me = response;
            $scope.status = true;
        })
    }
```

FB share loads default values (like  and ) from http://www.example.com/ and uses set href param (http://www.example.com/event). I tried with method: 'feed' as well, but without success.
I'm supposed to have several different share buttons on the page, so I guess meta og tags are not going to do it...

This is SPA with number of ui-view s, and ui-router using html5 works fine and everything works fine.

Comment: Facebook is in the process of removing all possibilities to specify these values at run-time, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations Having the server return the OG meta data when the URL is requested is the only way it will work after that.

Comment: So it definitely means that I have to use server side caching to be able to respond properly?

Comment: Yes. There’s services like prerender.io that can help with this, if you do not want to implement it all on your end.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Facebook crawlers are unable to render the javaScript!

Angular JS is less friendly when it comes to SEO integration.

Reviewing your code:

```
$scope.shareEvent = function (event) {
        console.log('verify values: ', event.image); // works fine!
        FacebookService.share({
            href: 'http://www.example.com/event/'+event_id+'/', // this value is passed
            title: event.title, // Not shown
            description: event.desc, // Not shown
            image: event.image // Not shown
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.me = response;
            $scope.status = true;
        })
    }

you said console.log(event.image);  / Works fine
```

> The reason is same, your browser is able to render the JavaScript. But
>   Facebook crawler is unable to process that javaScript.

Comment: Can you  please elaborate? Js is rendering og meta tags and it renders href, but does not render title and image? Is crawler visiting site when share button is pressed?

Comment: ogtags works when you directly assing values to them.

Comment: Can you recommend any solution to this issue?

Comment: I have a website and facing the same issue I tried using social share but end up with default facebook-share button, I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: Try  [Angular-universal](https://universal.angular.io/) or [prerender](https://prerender.io/)

Comment: I'll look at prerender. Universal is for angular 2? My app is not

Comment: Even your answer is helpful, it is not solution, nor offer one, so I cannot mark it as correct answer. I did gave you helpful vote though.